# integrate the following equation

Tags: calculus, integration

here is the equation:

[image]

here is my answer:

[image]

the correct answer:

$-\sqrt {1 - 2x} +c$

Comment: What's the antiderivative of $x^{-1/2}$?

Comment: The last equality is wrong: $\displaystyle \int \frac {u'(x)}{u(x)}\mathrm dx=\log \left(|u(x)|\right)$. Here you have $u(x)=(1-2x)^{1/2}$. What is $u'(x)$? It is not $-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=1-2x$ so $du=-2dx\implies dx=-{1\over 2}du$. Then
$$
\int (1-2x)^{-1/2}dx=-{1\over 2}\int u^{-1/2}du=-{1\over 2}{u^{1/2}\over 1/2}+C=-u^{1/2}+C=-(1-2x)^{1/2}+C.
$$

Your error occurs in the $\ln$ term where you didn't use the power rule correctly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{Let }\sqrt{1-2x}=u\implies \frac{-2dx}{\sqrt{1-2x}}=du$$

Use $$\int x^n dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$ as $n+1\ne0$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant

Comment: @Downvoter, I beg you to pinpoint the mistake